# How to get inner details of a Dynamic Content object Event in an Azure Logic App when creating an Alert Email

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Key vault, setup with DataGrid events to notify when keys near expiration.

From a Logic App, on event, I send a mail.  In the mail designer you can add the dynamic objects.

[image]

Looking at the Data Object, @{triggerBody()?['data']}, it returns a whole bunch of extra stuff.

[image]

It would be great if I could retun only portions of the Data object, such as Version,  Object name.  However I'm not aware of the syntax to access it under @{triggerBody()?['data']}

Answer (score 1):

You can add **['Version']**/**['ObjectName']** to the existing expression (i.e.`@{triggerBody()?['Data']['Version']`}/`@{triggerBody()?['Data']['ObjectName']}`)

[image]
[image]